# How to program the player to jump in a smooth and standard way in Lua?

Tags: lua, love2d

I have been learning to program games for four years, but I still do not know how the players can jump properly (I only need the basic jump method of platformer games but I still can not do it). I searched many tutorials online, but very few, or yes, those languages ​​are not the same as Lua.

Over the past 4 years, when I was making a platformer game, to make the character jump I tried many ways, each of which was incomplete and there was a bug (like players going through walls, stuck, when jumping it gets stuck in the wall on the player's head, and many other weird things).

Now I will present the most recent way I have tried. This is my player file: I am using the bump.lua library's support. Visit the library here: https://github.com/kikito/bump.lua.

This is my file:

```
Knight = Object:extend()

function Knight:new(x, y)
    --- properties
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.width = 36
    self.height = 48
    -----
    self.scaleX = 1
    ---- art 
    self.sprite = love.graphics.newImage("sources/art/player/knight/knight.png")
    self.grid = anim8.newGrid(48, 81, self.sprite:getWidth(), self.sprite:getHeight())
    self.animations = {}
    self.animations.idle = anim8.newAnimation(self.grid(1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1), 0.1)
    self.animations.walk = anim8.newAnimation(self.grid(4, 1, 5, 1, 6, 1, 7, 1, 8, 1, 4, 1), 0.05)
    self.animations.jump = anim8.newAnimation(self.grid(9, 1), 0.1)
    self.anim = self.animations.idle
    ----- 
    ----- physics value
    self.xVelocity = 0
    self.yVelocity = 0
    self.onGround = false
    self.gravity = 10
    --- add to bump world 
    world:add(self, self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
end

local knightFilter = function(item, other)
  if     other.isCoin   then return 'cross'
  elseif other.isBlock   then return 'slide'
  elseif other.isExit   then return 'touch'
  elseif other.isSpring then return 'bounce'
  end
  -- else return nil
end

function Knight:update(dt)
    if love.keyboard.isDown('a') then 
        self.xVelocity = -200
        self.scaleX = -1
    elseif love.keyboard.isDown('d') then
        self.xVelocity = 200
        self.scaleX = 1
    else
        self.xVelocity = 0
    end

    if self.onGround == false then self.yVelocity = self.yVelocity + self.gravity end

    local goalX, goalY = self.x + self.xVelocity * dt, self.y + self.yVelocity * dt
    local actualX, actualY, cols, len = world:move(self, goalX, goalY, knightFilter)
    self.x, self.y = actualX, actualY
    self.onGround = false
    for i = 1, len do
        local other = cols[i].other
        if other.isBlock then
            self.onGround = true
        else
            self.onGround = false
        end
    end

    self.anim:update(dt)
end

function Knight:draw()
    love.graphics.setColor(1, 1, 1)
    self.anim:draw(self.sprite, math.floor(self.x) + 18, math.floor(self.y) + 4, nil, self.scaleX, 1, 24, 36)
    love.graphics.rectangle("line", self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
end
```

And this is main.lua (You only need to pay attention to the functions `love.keypressed ()` and `love.keyreleased ()`):

```
Object = require "libs/classic"
bump = require "libs/bump"
anim8 = require "libs/anim8"

function love.load()
    world = bump.newWorld()
    addPlayer("knight")
    variableandrequire()
    --- gameplay level1
    loadDataLevel1()
    buildMap()
    -------
end

function variableandrequire()
    listOfBlocks = {}
    -----
    require "entities/blocks/block"
end

function love.update(dt)
    dt = math.min(dt, 0.025)
    player:update(dt)
end

function love.draw()
    player:draw()
    drawBlocks()
end

function drawBlocks()
    for i, v in ipairs(listOfBlocks) do
        v:draw()
    end
end

function addPlayer(name)
    local character = name
    if character == "knight" then
        require "entities/characters/knight"
        player = Knight (100, 100)
    end
end

function loadDataLevel1()
    map = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
           {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
           {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
           {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
           {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
           {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
           {0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
           {0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
           {0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
           {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},}

end

function buildMap()
    --id : 1.grass 2.dirt
    for y = 1, 10 do
        for x = 1, 15 do
            if map[y][x] == 1 then
                table.insert(listOfBlocks, Block((x - 1) * 64, (y - 1) * 64, 1))
            elseif map[y][x] == 2 then
                table.insert(listOfBlocks, Block((x - 1) * 64, (y - 1) * 64, 2))
            end
        end
    end
end

function love.keypressed(key) 
    if key == 'w' then
        if player.onGround then
            player.yVelocity = -350
            player.onGround = false
        end
    end
end

function love.keyreleased(key)
    if key == 'w' then
        if player.yVelocity < -60 then player.yVelocity = -60 end
    end
end
```

I have encountered the following bug: When the player is free-falling, the speed of falling is fine, but if the player is standing on a block then press the left or right button slowly until it falls (then the player touches close on the side of the wall), the speed of falling is very fast, and when the player stands close to the wall and jumps, the player seems to cling to the wall and climb slowly, although the wall is much higher than the jump height.

And I think this is my dump way to do it. Because it generates many bugs, one after another. And of course, the way I work is never perfect. All my life I would never know a standard method if no one taught.

I would be more than happy for you to share me a standard and basic jump method (I do not require too high), just jump looks smooth like most platformer games today (I appreciate this way). And equally important, it is performed in Lua.

Comment: The following links were recommended in an answer below: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9130QVnn7VU https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zDVZchjddbQ

Comment: The actual question here is confusing: the title talks about making a smooth jump, but all of the bugs and issues in the post relate to collision detection and correction. Are you asking how to create a smooth jump arc or how to handle collision when you landing from the jump?